# Density of non-lipschitz functions

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Fix a closed interval $I$. Prove that the non-lipschitz functions in $C(I)$ are dense in $C(I)$.

I don't even know where to begin! This is a question from a previous exam in a Real Analysis course I am taking. Does anyone have any idea how to prove it? Perhaps using some harmonic analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix any non-Lipschitz continuous function $g$. If $f$ is continuous then there exist polynomials $p_n$ converging uniformly to $f-g$. Now $g+p_n$ are non-Lipschtz functions converging to $f$.

Comment: your argument is fine in the case of a compact intervall $I$. But if $I$ is only closed ....

Comment: @Fred It is a common practice to refer to compact intervals $[a,b]$ as closed intervals.

Comment: The intervall $[0,\infty) $ is closed,  but not compact.